# XUL grid with an element spanning multiple columns

Tags: xul

How can I make a layout like this in XUL?

```
--------------------------------------------
elem11 | elem12 | elem13                   |
--------------------------------------------
elem21 | elem22 | elem23 | elem24 | elem25 |
--------------------------------------------
```

`<grid>` doesn't appear to allow one element to span multiple columns, unless I am missing something.

EDIT: XUL

```
<groupbox flex="1">
    <caption label="&options.general.keyBindings;" />
    <vbox flex="1">
        <hbox flex="1" align="center">
            <checkbox id="nextpleaseAllowNumberShortcuts" oncommand="nextplease.enableDisableNumberShortcutModifierMenu();"/>
            <menulist id="nextpleaseNumberShortcutModifier" prefstring="nextplease.numbermodifier" style="margin-right: 0">
                <menupopup onpopuphiding="nextplease.keyBindingsChanged = true;"/>
            </menulist>
            <label id="nextpleaseAllowNumberShortcuts1"/>
        </hbox>
        <separator class="thin"/>
        <grid>
            <columns>
                <column/>
                <column/>
                <column/>
                <column/>
                <column/>
                <column/>
            </columns>

            <rows>
                <row align="center">
                    <label value="&options.general.nextKey;" />
                    <menulist id="nextpleaseNextModifier" prefstring="nextplease.modifier">
                        <menupopup onpopuphiding="nextplease.onModifierMenuChange('nextkey', 'nextkeymenu', 'nextpleaseModifier');"/>
                    </menulist>
                    <label value="&options.general.enterKey;" />
                    <textbox id="nextkey" type="text" size="1" maxlength="1"
                        onchange="return nextplease.onKeyChange('nextkey', 'nextkeymenu', 'nextpleaseModifier');" />
                    <label value="&options.general.or;" />
                    <menulist id="nextkeymenu">
                        <menupopup onpopuphiding="return nextplease.onKeyMenuChange('nextkey', 'nextkeymenu', 'nextpleaseModifier');"/>
                    </menulist>
                </row>
                <row align="center">
                    <label value="&options.general.prevKey;" />
                    <menulist id="nextpleasePrevModifier" prefstring="nextplease.modifier">
                        <menupopup onpopuphiding="nextplease.onModifierMenuChange('prevkey', 'prevkeymenu', 'nextpleasePrevModifier');"/>
                    </menulist>
                    <label value="&options.general.enterKey;" />
                    <textbox id="prevkey" type="text" size="1" maxlength="1"
                        onchange="return nextplease.onKeyChange('prevkey', 'prevkeymenu', 'nextpleasePrevModifier');" />
                    <label value="&options.general.or;" />
                    <menulist id="prevkeymenu">
                        <menupopup onpopuphiding="return nextplease.onKeyMenuChange('prevkey', 'prevkeymenu', 'nextpleasePrevModifier');"/>
                    </menulist>
                </row>
                <row align="center">
                    <label value="&options.general.firstKey;" />
                    <menulist id="nextpleaseFirstModifier" prefstring="nextplease.modifier">
                        <menupopup onpopuphiding="nextplease.onModifierMenuChange('firstkey', 'firstkeymenu', 'nextpleaseFirstModifier');"/>
                    </menulist>
                    <label value="&options.general.enterKey;" />
                    <textbox id="firstkey" type="text" size="1" maxlength="1"
                        onchange="return nextplease.onKeyChange('firstkey', 'firstkeymenu', 'nextpleaseFirstModifier');" />
                    <label value="&options.general.or;" />
                    <menulist id="firstkeymenu">
                        <menupopup onpopuphiding="return nextplease.onKeyMenuChange('firstkey', 'firstkeymenu', 'nextpleaseFirstModifier');"/>
                    </menulist>
                </row>
                <row align="center">
                    <label value="&options.general.lastKey;" />
                    <menulist id="nextpleaseLastModifier" prefstring="nextplease.modifier">
                        <menupopup onpopuphiding="nextplease.onModifierMenuChange('lastkey', 'lastkeymenu', 'nextpleaseLastModifier');"/>
                    </menulist>
                    <label value="&options.general.enterKey;" />
                    <textbox id="lastkey" type="text" size="1" maxlength="1"
                        onchange="return nextplease.onKeyChange('lastkey', 'lastkeymenu', 'nextpleaseLastModifier');" />
                    <label value="&options.general.or;" />
                    <menulist id="lastkeymenu">
                        <menupopup onpopuphiding="return nextplease.onKeyMenuChange('lastkey', 'lastkeymenu', 'nextpleaseLastModifier');"/>
                    </menulist>
                </row>
            </rows>
        </grid>
    </vbox>
</groupbox>
```

What I wanted was to turn the `<hbox>` with `nextpleaseAllowNumberShortcuts` into a row of the grid below it. The checkbox with the label would be in the first column, the menu in the second one (the other rows have the same menu there), and the label span the rest of the columns.

Comment: Can you post your xul code? And, if has some, the XBL too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fake this by making a three column grid, and putting an hbox in the third column, second row.  You are correct that you cannot span multiple columns.

Comment: Unfortunately, this fails to work if I have 3 rows instead of 2. Simplified a bit too much.

Comment: The only way to do this with a single grid, if you are wanting a field to truly 'span' is to use the minimum number of columns -- in your case, three.

Comment: Then, in all of the other rows, you would need need to include an <hbox/> in the last column with all of the other 'columns'.  This may require some experimenting with the layout to get it to look the way you want.

Comment: Another, also hack-ish looking choice would be to put two grids side-by-side.  and try to make them look like it was just one grid.

Comment: Also - I'm also not sure what you mean when you say it fails to work -- I mean that you would have to put an hbox in the third column of any rows that contain more than three "columns".